# Opening URL inside docx file using Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, url, docx

I am currently working on an IOS app that allows users to view docx files within the app. These files have links inside them that link directly to outside sources, such as youtube videos.

The issue is that when any of these links inside the file are clicks, it gives this error and does nothing. [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNhRZ.png)

However, if you load up a file, press and hold the link, click the "share" button, and then click cancel, the links will work fine after that.

To load in the files, i'm using the Document Controller class.

Is there any way to dynamically detect when links inside a file are clicked, and then perform an action (such as open the associated url)?

Comment: Look at the error. It's an unrecognized selector regarding `NSURL isTelephonyURL`. A Google search reveals that may be from a library found on Github. It's certainly not a standard method.

Comment: I am having a similar issue.  I am using UIDocumentInteractionController to display PDFs that have hyperlinks in them.  If one is clicked the user is locked and can't do anything unless they close out of the app.  I found it works fine in older iOS versions 10.2 but in 10.3 it freezes the app...